# Getting subprocess error when using pip to install discord.py

Tags: python, pip, discord.py

Been trying to get a discord bot running, and I've tried plenty of different ways to install discord.py to no avail.

When I try running
`py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py` or its myriad of other variations, I always get this error (this is a shortened version of the error message):

```
  Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [110 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\aiohttp
      ...
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(1475): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Carlos-san\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3097): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Carlos-san\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3238): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Carlos-san\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3293): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Carlos-san\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3744): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'
      C:\Users\Carlos-san\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include\cpython/longintrepr.h(87): note: see declaration of '_longobject'
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.29.30133\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Haven't found any other post that was able to provide an adequate answer, any help is appreciated.
I am on Python 3.12, and don't usually program with it, for the record. I have also reinstalled python and pip twice.

Comment: Looks like `aiohttp`, a dependency of discord.py, does not support Python 3.12 yet: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/7639 The authors of the library are working on it, but in the meantime it looks like you have to downgrade your Python Version to 3.11

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning C4996: 'Py\_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/\_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob\_digit': is not a member of '\_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)