# warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openai-api, aiohttp

Newbie here.

I have been trying to installen the openai library into python, but I keep running into problems. I have already installed C++ libraries.

It seems to have problems specific with aio http, and I get the error below.
I a running a Windows 11 laptop without admin restrictions.

**Error**

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\include -IC:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22621.0\\cppwinrt" /Tcaiohttp/_websocket.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-312\Release\aiohttp/_websocket.obj
      _websocket.c
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(1475): warning C4996: 'Py_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12
      aiohttp/_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob_digit': is not a member of '_longobject'

[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp

Failed to build aiohttp

ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use `python 3.11`

or

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```

> installs their current beta release that supports python 3.12.x

then try `openai` installation

---

Link to git :https://github.com/KillianLucas/open-interpreter/issues/581

Answer (score 0):

As of February the 1st 2024, [multidict](https://pypi.org/project/multidict) released a wheel for Python 3.12.

You can [download it here](https://pypi.org/project/multidict/#files), but it will also be updated over the coming days in the affected libraries. `aiohttp` as an example updated theirs today (02-02-2024).

[Official Github link](https://github.com/aio-libs/multidict/releases/tag/v6.0.5)