# ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp and ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, discord.py, aiohttp, build-tools, pyproject.toml

I was trying to install `discord.py` beforehand and got the error about `Visual C++ 14` or something and i installed that now im getting these two errors and i dont know what to do.
Also above the `[end of output]` line i got this error: command

> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.37.32822\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2.

As i said i tried installing `Visual C++ 14` or something to fix the error and now its giving me entirely new errors and since im new to developping with python i dont understand what the errors mean. And the error above the `[end of output]` line is giving me Visual Studio 14 problems.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to help, at a minimum what command are you running, which version of Python are you using, a full error message etc. My guess is you're not using a supported version of Python so it's trying to build a package from source, which is often difficult on Windows. It looks like `discord.py` requires python 3.8, 3.9 or 3.10 - are you using one of these?

Comment: thank you for the help, i found out that discord.py doesn't accept python 3.12 so i installed 3.11 instead. Thank you!

Comment: And btw this is because aiohttp does not support python 3.12 (yet), And dpy use aiohttp as dependency

Comment: Does this answer your question? [warning C4996: 'Py\_OptimizeFlag': deprecated in 3.12 aiohttp/\_websocket.c(3042): error C2039: 'ob\_digit': is not a member of '\_longobject'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77388920/warning-c4996-py-optimizeflag-deprecated-in-3-12-aiohttp-websocket-c3042)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install aiohttp==3.9.0b0
```